# How do customize the Collections in Shopify?

Tags: html, css, e-commerce, shopify, liquid

I currently have a Shopify account that allows users to add some products to cart and checkout. It is currently in a grid format.

I am adding another type of product that are 'courses' and this would require users enter information such as Name, Contact details, etc. upon Adding to Cart / checkout. I would like these courses to be in a list view as well. How do I go about customizing this?

Comment: Too broad currently. Give examples and reference, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking to do is create a sort of subset for your collections. For instance **Courses>List of Courses** in which case the styling and structure will depend on your theme, but generally you can look at [this knowledge object which goes over how to achieve this and edit your theme files](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/collections/featuring-collections-using-link-lists).

[This article](https://www.envision.io/blogs/ecommerce-pulse/28829889-how-to-edit-the-css-of-your-shopify-theme) goes a bit more in depth with styling best practices and guidance, as well. Hopefully this helps, per your question it seems like you just needed some general information, but should you need more details just ask.